# Verification of Proof: Existence and Correctness of Linear Map h in Tensor Product Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, tensor-products, bilinear-operator

First some definitions:
$$ f: V_1 \rightarrow V_2 , linear$$
$$ g: W_1 \rightarrow W_2 , linear$$

$$ h': V_1 \times W_1 \rightarrow V_2 \times W_2 $$

$$ h: V_1 \otimes W_1 \rightarrow V_2 \otimes W_2 , (v_1 \otimes w_1) \mapsto f(v_1) \otimes g(w_1) 
$$

$$ v_1 \in V_1, \quad v_2 \in V_2, \quad w_1 \in W_1, \quad w_2 \in W_2 $$

I was supposed to prove that there exists a unique linear map h (as defined) for all $$v \in V_1, \quad v \in W_1$$
I have already proven the existence of the linear map, however I am unsure if my proof that $$(v_1 \otimes w_1) \mapsto f(v_1) \otimes g(w_1) 
$$ is correct.
Please take a look at it and let me know if something isn't right. Thank you!

proof: $$h(v_1 \otimes w_1) = v_2 \otimes w_2 \quad (1) $$
$$ v_2 \otimes w_2 = (\otimes \circ h')(v_1,w_1) 
= \otimes (h'(v_1,w_1)) 
= \otimes ((v_2,w_2)) 
= \otimes ((f(v_1),g(w_1))) 
= f(v_1) \otimes g(w_1) $$
therefore with (1) we have:
$$ f(v_1) \otimes g(w_1) = h(v_1 \otimes w_1)
$$

I used the tensor product symbol for both (the map and the operator). If it's infront of brackets, it's the map)

Comment: In order to prove the existence, did you use (or are you familiar with) the universal property? If so, you get existence and uniqueness all at once, and the map is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: @DiegoMarcon I did use the universal property. I argued that h' must be bilinear and defined b = ⊗ ∘ h′, Bc of the universal property we have for all vectorspaces U and all β: V1×V2 -> U,  ϕ: V1⊗W1 -> U , where ϕ linear and β = ϕ ∘ ⊗. Now choose U =  V2⊗W2. But now I still prove : b(v1,v2) = ⊗(h'(v1,w1)) = ϕ(v1⊗w1) and  ⊗(h'(v1,w1))  = v2⊗w2 = f(v1)⊗g(w1) =>  ϕ(v1⊗w1)  = f(v1)⊗g(w1) , now lets say h = ϕ. Did I miss something? I am still unsure of the last part. I aprecciate your help!

Comment: I think you are in the right path, but you should see that the proof ends when you choose $U = V_2 \otimes W_2$, there is nothing else to check. Let us rewrite your argument as follows: define $b: V_1 \times W_1 \longrightarrow V_2 \otimes W_2$ by $b(v_1, w_1) = \otimes \circ h'(v_1, w_1) = f(v_1) \otimes g(w_1)$. Since it is bilinear, the universal property ensures the existence of a unique linear $h: V_1 \otimes W_1 \longrightarrow V_2 \otimes W_2$ such that $h(v_1 \otimes w_1) = f(v_1) \otimes g(w_1)$.